# highcharts in arcgis api for JavaScript

Tags: highcharts, arcgis

Currently I am working on a feature layer of arcgis API for JavaScript. I want to show the graph with respect to my layers. Is it possible? If yes, then how can I add highchart on my map?

Here is the graph, which I want to show on my arcgis map:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fiber Position in BTK'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Arial',
            y: 61.41

        }, {
            name: 'Burried',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 10.85
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Hi Software Engineer, I do not know arcgis abilities, but Highcharts creates a graph in HTML element with specific dimensions by using JS code. So if arcgis allow you to add a layer as HTML element, it should work.

Comment: @ppotaczek yes some how it allow html , thanks i'll check this accordingly!!